# Какой есть плагин для поиска на сайте wordpress с возможностью выбора категорий для поиска?

Tags: wordpress, поиск, плагин

Подскажите, пожалуйста, плагин для поиска для сайта `wordpress` с возможностью выбора категорий для поиска. Меня бы полностью устроил вот этот **Facetious**, но он не работает, если выбрать в настройках **post type: no restriction**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по всей видимости, т.к. давно не обновлялся и не поддерживает последний версии wordpress. Если же выбрать, например, post, то все работает, но мне поиска по одному типу поста мало. Есть ли какой-то аналог?

Comment: Если это он https://github.com/cftp/facetious - то форкнуть и поправить под свой вкус

Comment: @A K но, я не столько с ним на ты, чтобы разобраться где у него косяк, почему тип без ограничений не воспринимает

Comment: Попробуйте на фриланс.ру поспрашивать, может не так и дорого будет сделать исправление.